# SSL has disappeared in wireshark

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I have a question for you guys. I downloaded wireshark a few hours ago. I searched a little bit on the internet and I found out you can decrypt SSL browser traffic. I followed a tutorial how to do that but I am stuck at one point. They say you have to go to edit > preferences > protocols > and here you have to find SSL. My problem is that it isn't there by me. I hope somebody of you have an solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for TLS...

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSL protocol is deprecated in favor of TLS.

TLS is what websites use these days for a secure connection, so select TLS from the protocol list and it will decode the traffic.